# Switching between monitors in dual-head setup

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, gnome

I'm using gnome in a dual-head setup with individual desktops. Is there any way to "jump" to another monitor using the keyboard only? Now the only method I know is to move the mouse pointer to the another screen and click on something there. Can I do something like that without using the mouse?

Comment: Are you saying you want to change focus to the other display or you actually want to bounce the cursor over there without taking the long way?

Comment: @Shinrai, I don't quite understand the difference. I'll give an example: I have two text editors, one on each monitor. How can I write in one and then in another without touching my mouse?

Comment: So, the former.  (By the latter I mean, there are some apps with a hotkey for 'move my mouse cursor to monitor X' - sort of pointless in a dual screen setup but if you have, say, 16 displays it's easier than getting a mousing area the size of a desk.)

Answer (score 1):

try looking up the software called "Splunk".. Seems to be a pretty highly praised desktop swapping software for linux.

Comment: On Splunk's site I've found something completely different. Here's how they describe their product: "Splunk is an engine for your IT data. It collects, indexes and harnesses all the fast moving IT data generated by your applications, servers and devices — physical, virtual and in the cloud."

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using Xinerama, instead of your window manager's multi-head support.  If you disable xinerama, both monitors on the same workspace.  (I'm not talking about a cloned view, either.)

If they are truly separate workspaces (by desktop I think you mean workspace), with separate task bars, then Ctrl-Alt- is probably the key binding will scroll between them.

You might be using Compiz or Metacity as the actual window managers.  I use Compiz, and find it highly configurable.  You might not have the configuration tools installed to change your default WM settings; install them and explore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between windows on the current desktop?

Comment: On the current desktop it works, of course. However, each monitor contains a different desktop.